# How can a program work with one set of args, but also in pipes?

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, stdin

Say a program `uppercase`, that will work in either of two ways:

```
> uppercase "willy wonka"
WILLY WONKA

> cat names.txt | uppercase
CHARLIE
VIOLET
MIKE
```

Reading from `os.Args` works fine for the first and using `bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)` works fine for the latter, but how do programs implement both at once?

Comment: The more common convention is that if there is an argument, it's the name of a file to read from; barring that, read from standard input. That's how the vast majority of standard tools such as grep/sed/awk and friends handle this.

Answer (score 0):

But that depends on how you want to implement that.

You can make the two modes mutually exclusive—if at least a single command-line argument is passed in the invocation, the program operates solely on command-line arguments, and ignores (does not read) its standard input stream,—and if no command-line aruments are specified, it reads its standard input stream, and if your program were to "merge" the data from the both sources, the transformations of the words taken from the command-line arguments would come up either before or after the words shoveled form the `stdin`.
I, for one, would find that puzzling for the general case.

Or you can make the program consume both "sources" of data. Here comes the problem of priority: which one is processed first.
The additional problem is that typically if a program implements a "transformer", I expect that if pass N lines to the program's standard input stream, I expect N transformed lines to come through its standard output stream.

So I'd go with the first approach.
That would be a single `if` statement.